# Count points on linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, line, linestring

I have a table `table_point` with points that are located on linestrings (`table_line`). How would I count for each segement of the a `linestring` of `table_lines` the number of `points` that are located on it?

Comment: I would first convert lines to segments to segment_table (http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html).
Then JOIN by intersection the new segment_table on the point_table with a count and a GroupBy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to guarantee robustness I recommend to run a *(K)NN* search on the dumped segments:

```
WITH
  segs AS (
    SELECT
      l.id, dmp.path[1] AS seq,
      ST_MakeLine(dmp.geom, LEAD(dmp.geom) OVER(PARTITION BY l.id ORDER BY dmp.path)) AS geom
    FROM
      table_line AS l,
      LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(l.geom) AS dmp
    )
SELECT
  nn.id, nn.seq,
  COUNT(p.id) AS cnt
FROM
  table_point AS p
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      id, seq
    FROM
      segs
    ORDER BY
      segs.geom <-> p.geom
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS nn
GROUP BY
  1, 2
;
```